# Replacing ascii with matching characters using perl / awk or other

Tags: regex, linux, perl, awk

I have an access log that was written with nginx and lua code.
It is url encoded and those some characters are written in the format of \xHexCode (for example, double quotes are written as \x22).
I would like to run awk or perl or other fast script to replace it back.

Comment: Post sample input and expected output and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gnu-awk` like this:

```
str='\x22 \x41 written as \x22).'

awk -v RS='\\\\x[0-9]+' 'RT{ORS=sprintf("%c", strtonum("0" substr(RT, 2)))} 1' <<< "$str"
" A written as ").
```

This is how it is working:

1. Using `RS='\\\\x[0-9]+'` we're separating custom record separator for each of those `\xNN` numbers.
2. `substr(RT, 2)` takes `x41` from `\x41`
3. `strtonum("0" substr(RT, 2))` adds `0` to make it `0x41` and returns ascii code `65`.
4. `printf "%c"` prints equivalent ascii character `A` from `65`.
5. `ORS=...` sets output record separator same as the return value of `sprintf`.